# Game crashes with 0.9.10 and 0.9.11 of google play games plugin for unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have tested my game with every version up to 0.9.07 and it works well but with 0.9.10 and 0.9.11 it crashes. I see the initial google play screen asking me to log in but after logging in it crashes.
Device: Moto X(2013) running android 4.4
Unity version: 4.6.1
Google Play services: rev 22
Here are the logs:

```
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:57 +05:30 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:57 +05:30 DEBUG: Creating real IPlayGamesClient
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:57 +05:30 DEBUG: Entering state: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:57 +05:30 DEBUG: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:57 +05:30 DEBUG: Entering state: ShutdownState
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:57 +05:30 DEBUG: ShutdownState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): Invalid levelID format levelID: -1
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:58 +05:30 DEBUG: PlayGamesHelperObject.OnApplicationFocus True
I/Unity (10214): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity (10214): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/19/14 18:45:59 +05:30 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: VALID
```

Using GamesNativeSDK tag:

```
E/GamesNativeSDK(10214): Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.hidden.hiddenGameName/app_.gpg.classloader/4da25210572e7e07ea67142ded62c42e.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
I/GamesNativeSDK(10214): Auth operation started: SIGN IN
I/GamesNativeSDK(10214): Connecting to Google Play...
V/GamesNativeSDK(10214): Play Games callback indicates connection.
I/GamesNativeSDK(10214): Successfully connected to Google Play.
```

Comment: Hmm. i looked at the code for the plugin and did not see the message "Invalid levelID" anywhere.  Could this be in your game code?

Comment: Yes. That's from my game. Its not fatal. So, it shouldnt be causing the crash.

Comment: I don't see anything google play games related that is crashing - is there anything in the log when the game crashes (don't filter the log tags).